# Docker entrypoint doesn't find command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the [znc docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/znc/) in docker-compose. I have tried to follow the docs, using `--makeconf`, but something's wrong with my config.

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting server_znc_service_1 ... done
Attaching to server_znc_service_1
znc_service_1  | /entrypoint.sh: exec: line 6: znc: not found
server_znc_service_1 exited with code 127
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  znc_service:
    image: library/znc
    volumes:
      - znc-cfg-volume:/znc-data
    ports:
      - "6697:6697"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "znc.localhost"
    command: ["znc", "--makeconf"]

volumes:
  znc-cfg-volume:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all compose container with no-start:

```
docker-compose up --no-start
```

Then if you try to run it, you will see reasons:

```
$ docker run -it znc
[ .. ] Checking for list of available modules...
[ >> ] ok
[ .. ] Opening config [/znc-data/configs/znc.conf]...
[ !! ] No such file
[ ** ] Restart ZNC with the --makeconf option if you wish to create this config.
[ ** ] Unrecoverable config error.
```

Then just run with make conf:

```
docker run -it znc --makeconf
[ .. ] Checking for list of available modules...
[ >> ] ok
[ ** ]
[ ** ] -- Global settings --
[ ** ]
[ ?? ] Listen on port (1025 to 65534):
```

Comment: Ok that's progress, thanks. How can I then use `docker-compose up` to start it after making this configuration with `docker run`?

Comment: Honestly I know nothing about ZNC :) A long configuration wizard is coming there which I broke up. I believe it will form conf file after that and you will be ok to rerun the image with just docker run. And you don't need to compose it again